# Equivalent of Index options (SQL Server) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I am recreating a database existing in SQL Server in Oracle. I am a novice in DDL and new to Oracle. I have come across the following table in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE [DailyCounts](
    [LDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_LDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [SourceTable] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [TableRowCount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DailyCounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The table stores daily row counts for each of large tables in the database about 4 tables (4 rows per day).

What is the equivalent table definition for above table in Oracle especially the equivalent for the [index options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188677.aspx) in Oracle? I don't know anything about index options and if they are required in this case.

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_DailyCounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I know `ON PRIMARY` is [not required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798213/what-does-on-primary-mean#comment5813710_2798232) in the above query, [Oracle doesn't have clustered indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468466/2246380) and that Oracle creates [indexes for primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15704189/2246380). Thus personally I feel the following query should do the job.

```
CREATE TABLE DailyCounts(
    LDate timestamp DEFAULT sysdate CONSTRAINT PK_DailyCounts PRIMARY KEY,
    SourceTable varchar2(32) NOT NULL,
    TableRowCount number(19) NOT NULL
 );
```

Comment: The equivalent of a clustered index in SQL Server is an index organized table in Oracle. But I agree your `CREATE TABLE` looks good, although I prefer `timestamp` over `date` just to document that fact that the time part *is* important.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Agree with changing `date` to `timestamp`. What to do with the index options (`PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80`) in Oracle? I don't know anything about index options, if they are required in this case and if they have a equivalent in Oracle?

Comment: Keep the defaults for Oracle, in most of the cases they make sense.

Comment: I can't emphasize enough how bad an idea it is to use `date`, `datetime`, or `timestamp` as a field in a primary key. Foreign keys become a pain, you suddenly care about clock precision, and events like Daylight Saving Time or VM migrations can wreak havoc on your time accuracy. This table defined here, for example, can *never have multiple simultaneous row inserts* because that would be a key violation! Then there's stuff like SQL Server treats times in `datetime` within 3ms as the same for comparison... more key violations.

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks. I understand. I didn't design or create the tables in SQL Server and I have been assigned the job of just converting the SQL Server code to Oracle code not changing the design. I will bring it up in the next meeting.